# How to use easyui dialog with Angular2

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-easyui

Can anyone tell me, how to use easyui dialog with Angular2?

```
<div id="tplDialog" class="easyui-dialog" name="tplDialog"                
    data-options="iconCls:'icon-save',modal:true, closed:true"
    style="width: 600px; height: 368px; padding: 0px;display: none;"></div>
```

i use `jq('#tplDialog').dialog('open')`,it returns `Cannot read property 'options' of undefined`, but `jq('#tplDialog').show()` works correctly.
I don't konw why `$.data(_23a, "panel")` is undefined in jquery.easyui.min.js

Comment: try adding `declare var $: any` and `declare var jq: any` to your component's code right after the imports (before the `@component` decorator)

Comment: would you add the complete code? I have a strong feeling there's something wrong

Comment: i have adding `declare var jq:any` and`declare var $:any` in components.ts .The code can works when i don't use angular2. The mistake happens at `$.data(_23a,"panel")`in `jquey.easyui.js`,using angular2 or not ,the parameter _23a is the same but the return is different.